# Edit the method for using System.in and System.out

Tags: java, inputstream, system.out, system.in, printstream

I have this methods

```
    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("out.txt");
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream("out.txt");
    Transit.outputTransport(Parking, os);
    System.out.println(Parking.toString());
    Transport forOut = Transit.inputTransport(is);
    System.out.println(forOut.toString());
    System.out.println();
```

I need change sources from fileoutput to System.out and fileinput for System.in and realize it in code. How can i do this? Transit.outputTransport(Parking, os) - writing byte string in file and Transit.inputTransport(is) - return object after translate bytes to normal form

Comment: replace `is` with `System.in` and `os` with `System.out`

Comment: thank you for help, but it doesn`t work

Comment: "it doesn't work", do you get errors? Do you see no output? Does it still write to a file?  Could you please specify

Comment: Apps is running and waiting something on stage Transport forOut = Transit.inputTransport(System.in); what should i write here?

Comment: Maybe you need to run the command with standard input / output redirected; e.g. `java MyMainClass < in.txt > out.txt`.

Comment: Note that your example seems to be reading AND writing `out.txt`.  That is broken.  1) When you open a file for output (like that) it immediately truncates the file.  2) If you try to read and write a file at the same time, the results will be difficult to predict.

Comment: @JayCastle what happens when you write some text into the console. Seems that the app is waiting on input

Comment: @Lino Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:105) - there System.out.println(forOut.toString());

Comment: @StephenC but it works for my app and it`s all that i need know, but it doesn`t work for system.in and system.out

Answer (score 1):

```
PrintStream os = new PrintStream(System.out);
Transit.outputTransport(Parking, os);
System.out.println(Parking.toString());
os.close();

InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(System.in);
Transport forOut = Transit.inputTransport(is);
System.out.println(forOut.toString());
System.out.println();
is.close();
```

Comment: it wont work, cuz inputTransport has InputStream param, not scanner

Comment: @JayCastle - I've updated my answer. Feel free to comment if you still face any problem.

Comment: You are most welcome.

Comment: Can u help with one more thing. What should i write in console for exit code 0? Console`s waiting some symbol or anythign else and when i enter something i have this error: null
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:246)

Comment: And now i have another problem forOut - everytime null

Comment: You may put `System.exit(0)` in your code based on the `null` check i.e. something like `if(something==null){System.exit(0);}` where `something` is the value to check for `null`. I can suggest more precisely if I see the complete code. I suggest you post a new question for this problem so that it can get more attention.

Comment: I create new post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60098656/fix-the-prolem-with-using-system-in-out-for-read-write-objects-in-by-file